# scanf не присваивает значение в C

Tags: c, scanf

StartX не принимает значение введенное посредством scanf().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define NUM 108

double  startX, deltaX, endX;

double function1(double x) {
  return log(1 - NUM / sin(x));
}

double function2(double x) {
  return tan(x) / NUM;
}


double decideFUNC(){
  double x, f1, f2;
  for(x = startX; x <= endX; x += deltaX) {
    f1 = function1(x);
    f2 = function2(x);
    if (f1 == f2) { // вряд ли мы сюда попадем
      printf("max values are the same %f\n", f1);
    } else {
      if (f1 > f2) 
        printf("x = %f, f1 = %f (%f, %f)\n", x, f1, f1, f2);
      else 
        printf("x = %f, f2 = %f (%f, %f)\n", x, f2, f1, f2);
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  scanf("%f", &startX);
  deltaX = 4;
  endX = 100;
  decideFUNC();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Попробуй scanf_s, как вариант.

Comment: %lf нужно для double

Comment: В дополнение к вышесказанному, для единообразия рекомендуется использовать `%lf` и в `printf`, хоть формально это и не обязательно.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте правильный модификатор -

```
scanf("%lf",&startX);
```

Ведь у вас переменная - `double` (`%lf`), а не `float` (`%f`).

Answer (score 0):

Постарайтесь не использовать scanf, его клинит если на входе неправильные символы. Делайте лучше так:

```
char str[100];
int n;

gets(str);
n = sscanf(str, "%lf", &startX);
if(n != 1)
    fprintf(stderr, "ошибка ввода.\n");
```

Comment: Постарайтесь не использовать `gets`. Функцию `gets` уже убрали и из стандартной библиотеки C, и из стандартной библиотеки С++.

Comment: да понятно, просто для примера